# Llamar Action desde el mismo Controller Api Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Tengo el siguiente Action:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{InvoiceId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateInvoice( [FromRoute]  int InvoiceId )
        {
          // Operaciones..
         }
```

Y deseo llamarlo desde el mismo Controller , en otro Action:

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> OtroAction()
            {
               .......
               var result=CreatedAtAction("CreateInvoice", new { InvoiceId = obj.InvoiceId});

 }
```

Pero esto simplemente no me funciona , no sucede absolutamente nada ,tampoco si agrego un punto de interrupción en el CreateInvoice.

Que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Perdón la curiosidad, ¿Porqué querrías hacerlo de esa manera?, ¿no sería mejor tener un tercer método que encapsule la lógica que necesitas e invocar dicho método en ambos Action?.

Comment: @CamiloBernal claro , es mi idea a futuro , pero ahora mismo deseo resolverlo de esta manera

Comment: Ya revisaste esto?: [Tipos de valor devuelto de acción del controlador de la API web de ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: @CamiloBernal  excelente ejemplo, si he formado esa lógica antes , usando repositories.

Comment: Fijate en la última parte (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1#synchronous-action) dan un ejemplo con CreatedAtAction.

Comment: Como dice @CamiloBernal la opcion es un tercer metodo, no te toma ni dos minutos crear un nuevo metodo para llamarlo desde las dos acciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es una buena práctica llamar a funciones del controlador para reutilizar código, es mejor crear una capa intermedia de servicios que contenga toda la lógica que usarás luego en cada uno de los métodos de tu controlador, es decir, algo como esto:

Clase de servicio:

```
namespace Business.Services
{

    public interface IInvoiceService
    {
        Task<bool> CreateInvoiceAsync(int invoiceId);
    }

    public class InvoiceService : IInvoiceService
    {
        #region Constructor

        public InvoiceService()
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region Métodos públicos

        public async Task<bool> CreateInvoiceAsync(int invoiceId)
        {
            Invoice invoice = new Invoice(invoiceId);

            //Métodos y logica de insercción de invoices

            return invoice;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Se define en el startup:

```
services.AddScoped<IInvoiceService, InvoiceService>();
```

Creas la inyección de dependencia en el controlador y utilizas la función en cada uno de los métodos que lo requieran:

```
public class InvoiceController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IInvoiceService _invoiceService;

    public InvoiceController(IInvoiceService invoiceService) 
    {
        _invoiceService = invoiceService;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]/{InvoiceId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateInvoice( [FromRoute]  int InvoiceId )
    {
        _await invoiceService.CreateInvoiceAsync(InvoiceId);
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OtroAction()
    {
        ...
        var result = await _invoiceService.CreateInvoiceAsync(obj.InvoiceId);
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, al final lo tuve que resolver de esa manera, por esa razón la marco como respuesta , pero aun sigo con la duda porque no me funciono la llamada del Action...